# GCP AI Platform API - Object Detection Metrics at Class Level (Python)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have trained a AutoML Object Detection model in Vertex AI (a service under AI Platform in GCP). I am trying to access model evaluation metrics for each label (precision, recall, accuracy etc.) for varying Confidence Score Threshold and IoU Threshold.

However, I am stuck at step one, even to get model's aggerate performance metric much less to the performance metric at granular levels. I have followed [this instruction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models?authuser=1#aggregate) But I cannot seem to figure out what is `evaluation_id` (also see the official sample code snippet [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/model_service/get_model_evaluation_image_object_detection_sample.py)), which is:

```
def get_model_evaluation_image_object_detection_sample(
    project: str,
    model_id: str,
    evaluation_id: str,
    location: str = "us-central1",
    api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
):
    # The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
    # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    client = aiplatform.gapic.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    name = client.model_evaluation_path(
        project=project, location=location, model=model_id, evaluation=evaluation_id
    )
    response = client.get_model_evaluation(name=name)
    print("response:", response)
```

After sometime I have figured out that for model trained in EU,  and `api_endpoint` shall be passed as:

```
location: str = "europe-west4"
api_endpoint: str = "europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
```

But whatever I try for `evaluation_id` leads to the following errors:

```
InvalidArgument: 400 List of found errors:  1.Field: name; Message: Invalid ModelEvaluation resource name.
```

There in the documentation it says (which is seems it contains what I need):

> For the bounding box metric, Vertex AI returns an array of metric
> values at different IoU threshold values (between 0 and 1) and
> confidence threshold values (between 0 and 1). For example, you can
> narrow in on evaluation metrics at an IoU threshold of 0.85 and a
> confidence threshold of 0.8228. By viewing these different threshold
> values, you can see how they affect other metrics such as precision
> and recall.

Without knowing that is contained in the output array, how would that work for each class? Basically I need for each class the model metrics for varying IoU threshold values and confidence threshold.

Also I have tried to query from AutoML API instead, like:

```
client_options = {'api_endpoint': 'eu-automl.googleapis.com:443'}

client = automl.AutoMlClient(client_options=client_options)
# Get the full path of the model.
model_full_id = client.model_path(project_id, "europe-west4", model_id)

print("List of model evaluations:")
for evaluation in client.list_model_evaluations(parent=model_full_id, filter=""):
    print("Model evaluation name: {}".format(evaluation.name))
    print("Model annotation spec id: {}".format(evaluation.annotation_spec_id))
    print("Create Time: {}".format(evaluation.create_time))
    print("Evaluation example count: {}".format(evaluation.evaluated_example_count))
    print(
        "Classification model evaluation metrics: {}".format(
            evaluation.classification_evaluation_metrics
        )
    )
```

No surprise, also this doesn't work, and leads to:

```
InvalidArgument: 400 List of found errors:  1.Field: parent; Message: The provided location ID doesn't match the endpoint. For automl.googleapis.com, the valid location ID is `us-central1`. For eu-automl.googleapis.com, the valid location ID is `eu`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the response of the model evaluation using [aiplatform_v1](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform.html) which is well documented and this is the reference linked from the [Vertex AI reference page](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/client-libraries?authuser=1#client_libraries).

On this script I ran [list_model_evaluations()](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/model_service.html#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient.list_model_evaluations) to get the evaluation name and used it as input for [get_model_evaluation()](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/model_service.html#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient.get_model_evaluation) which will return the evaluation details for Confidence Score Threshold, IoU Threshold, etc.

NOTE: I don't have a trained model in `europe-west4` so I used `us-central1` instead. But if you have trained in `europe-west4` you should use `https://europe-west4-aiplatform.googleapis.com` as `api_endpoint` as per [location document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/locations#specifying_the_location_using_the).

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform

api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
client_model = aiplatform.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
project_id = 'your-project-id'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = '999999999999'

model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
list_eval_request = aiplatform.types.ListModelEvaluationsRequest(parent=model_name)
list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(request=list_eval_request)
eval_name=''
for val in list_eval:
    eval_name = val.name

get_eval_request = aiplatform.types.GetModelEvaluationRequest(name=eval_name)
get_eval = client_model.get_model_evaluation(request=get_eval_request)
print(get_eval)
```

See response snippet:

```
name: "projects/xxxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/models/999999999999/evaluations/1234567890"
metrics_schema_uri: "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/image_object_detection_metrics_1.0.0.yaml"
metrics {
  struct_value {
    fields {
      key: "boundingBoxMeanAveragePrecision"
      value {
        number_value: 0.20201288
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "boundingBoxMetrics"
      value {
        list_value {
          values {
            struct_value {
              fields {
                key: "confidenceMetrics"
                value {
                  list_value {
                    values {
                      struct_value {
                        fields {
                          key: "confidenceThreshold"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.06579724
                          }
                        }
                        fields {
                          key: "f1Score"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.15670435
                          }
                        }
                        fields {
                          key: "precision"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.09326923
                          }
                        }
                        fields {
                          key: "recall"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.48989898
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    values {
                      struct_value {
....
```

**EDIT 1: Get response per class**

To get metrics per class, you can use [list_model_evaluation_slices()](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/model_service.html#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient.list_model_evaluation_slices) to get the name for each class, then use the name to [get_model_evaluation_slice()](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/model_service.html#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient.get_model_evaluation_slice). In this code I pushed the names to a list since I have multiple classes. Then just use the values stored in the array to get the metric per class.

In my code I used `label[0]` to get a single response from this class.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform

api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
client_model = aiplatform.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
project_id = 'your-project-id'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = '999999999999'

model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
list_eval_request = aiplatform.types.ListModelEvaluationsRequest(parent=model_name)
list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(request=list_eval_request)
eval_name=''
for val in list_eval:
    eval_name = val.name

label=[]
slice_eval_request = aiplatform.types.ListModelEvaluationSlicesRequest(parent=eval_name)
slice_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluation_slices(request=slice_eval_request)
for data in slice_eval:
    label.append(data.name)

get_eval_slice_request = aiplatform.types.GetModelEvaluationSliceRequest(name=label[0])
get_eval_slice = client_model.get_model_evaluation_slice(request=get_eval_slice_request)
print(get_eval_slice)
```

Print all classes:
[image]

Classes in UI:
[image]

Response snippet for a class:

```
name: "projects/xxxxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/models/999999999/evaluations/0000000000/slices/777777777"
slice_ {
  dimension: "annotationSpec"
  value: "Cheese"
}
metrics_schema_uri: "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/image_object_detection_metrics_1.0.0.yaml"
metrics {
  struct_value {
    fields {
      key: "boundingBoxMeanAveragePrecision"
      value {
        number_value: 0.14256561
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "boundingBoxMetrics"
      value {
        list_value {
          values {
            struct_value {
              fields {
                key: "confidenceMetrics"
                value {
                  list_value {
                    values {
                      struct_value {
                        fields {
                          key: "confidenceThreshold"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.06579724
                          }
                        }
                        fields {
                          key: "f1Score"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.10344828
                          }
                        }
                        fields {
                          key: "precision"
                          value {
                            number_value: 0.06198347
                          }
                        }
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works like a charm with aiplatform_v1 and your imports! I get now the evaluation_id for a specific model_id. It returns a long json with all confidence threshold and its corresponding metrics; not sure if it is per class or! BUT IoU  and class labels are missing. I would liked to get metrics for varying thresholds per class. Any ideas?

Comment: @TwinPenguins I updated my answer to include metrics per class.

Comment: Wow, works as intended. I saw slices, but figure out they are classes. Wonder why things are not explicit. Thanks